# How to find the Lie algebra of a specific subgroup of a product Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

My question is about finding the Lie algebra of a specific Lie group.
Start with a Lie group $G$, with normal Lie subgroup $C \unlhd G$. Then define the following subgroup $\hat{G} \leq G \times G$:
\begin{equation}
\hat{G} = \{ (g_{1}, g_{2}) \in G \times G \mid g_{2}g_{1}^{-1} \in C \}.
\end{equation}
I want to show that the Lie algebra of $\hat{G}$ is the following
\begin{equation}
Lie(\hat{G}) = \{ (X,Y) \in Lie(G \times G) \mid X - Y \in Lie(C) \}.
\end{equation}
Note that I am using the fact that $Lie(\hat{G}) = \{ (X,Y) \in Lie(G \times G) \mid \exp(t(X,Y)) \in \hat{G} \text{ for all } t \}$. With this fact  I was able to show containment in one direction; namely, if $\exp(t(X,Y)) = (\exp(tX), \exp(tY)) \in \hat{G}$ for all $t$, then $\exp(tY)\exp(-tX) \in C$ for all $t$, and so differentiating at $t = 0$ we find that $Y - X \in Lie(C)$.

I tried a few things for showing the other containment, but nothing which seemed to be in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is crucial for your case that $C$ is a normal subgroup, hence that $Lie(C)$ is an ideal in the Lie algebra. Then observe that if $X-Y \in Lie(C)$ we must also have $Lie(C) \ni [X-Y, Y] = [X, Y]$ since $Lie(C)$ is an ideal, hence specifically iterated Lie brackets of $X$ and $Y$ all lie in $Lie(C)$. Then you can use the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula to write:
$$
\exp(tX)\exp(-tY) = \exp(t(X-Y) + \frac{t^2}{2}[X,Y] + \dots)
$$
for sufficiently small $t$. And all later terms in the dots are iterated Lie brackets of $X$ and $Y$, hence the expression in the exponential lies in $Lie(C)$.

Comment: Would this also work in the following generalized case: $C \unlhd H \leq G$ (but $C$ not normal in $G$). And we define $\hat{G} = \{ (h,g) \in H \times G \mid \ gh^{-1} \in C \}$.

Comment: To be more precise, you only need to require that, say $X-Y \in Lie(C)$ and that $[X,Lie(C)] \subseteq Lie(C)$. Since we can always replace $Y = (Y-X) + X$. So in any term with iterated brackets, once we make the above substitution for $Y$, we only have terms in $Lie(C)$ and terms which bracket to $Lie(C)$.

Comment: Yes but that works because if $gh^{-1} \in C$ we must have $g \in Ch \subset H$. So then you might as well consider the case $H \times H$.